# Insert missing records from one table to another using mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I don't know why I am confused with this query.

I have two table: `Table A` with `900` records and `Table B` with `800` records. Both table need to contain the same data but there is some mismatch.

I need to write a mysql query to insert missing `100` records from `Table A` to `Table B`.

In the end, both `Table A` and `Table B` should be identical.

I do not want to truncate all the entries first and then do a insert from another table. So please any help is appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: You need to have two queries here, the first query is to `INSERT` records on table B from table A. The second query is vice versa since there are possibilities that records of table B are not on table A.

Comment: why you don't want to truncate if that is a really simple and fast solution?

Comment: John: Table B records need not be entered to Table A in this case. Only missing entries of Table A are to be entered into Table B.

Comment: jcho360: I want to know a better way to do it using a script rather than using truncate. :)

Comment: @Rikin ok, its your call. anyway, how many column names are there in each table?

Comment: @JohnWoo: I have 6 columns in each table with the same table definition. I would like to insert the missing records in Table B from Table A. Thank you for your help

Answer (score 21, accepted):

It is also possible to use `LEFT OUTER JOIN` for that. This will avoid subquery overhead (when system might execute subquery one time for *each* record of outer query) like in John Woo's answer, and will avoid doing unnecessary work overwriting already existing 800 records like in user2340435's one:

```
INSERT INTO b
SELECT a.* FROM a
LEFT OUTER JOIN b ON b.id = a.id
WHERE b.id IS NULL;
```

This will first select all rows from `A` and `B` tables including all columns from both tables, but for rows which exist in `A` and don't exist in `B` all columns for `B` table will be `NULL`.
Then it filter only such latter rows (`WHERE b.id IS NULL`),
and at last it inserts all these rows into `B` table.

Comment: Much better choice.  Seeing "SELECT id FROM table2" in the accepted answer made me cringe @ a table with 50 million rows...

Answer (score 5):

I think you can use `IN` for this. (*this is a simpliplification of your query*)

```
INSERT INTO table2 (id, name)
SELECT id, name
FROM table1
WHERE (id,name) NOT IN 
       (SELECT id, name
        FROM table2);
```

## [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/744755/2)

AS you can see on the demonstration, `table2` has only 1 records but after executing the query, 2 records were inserted on `table2`.

Comment: How about inserting all the records and not only selected ones ??

Comment: Can you give the structure of you tables?

Comment: same structure applicable for both  Table 1 and Table 2

Comment: @Rikin then you need to specify all column names :)

Comment: How about: INSERT INTO table2 SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE value NOT IN (SELECT value FROM table2);

Comment: since value is the column which has different data in both tables

Comment: @Rikin I'm not sure about the query you provided, but you can try it :D

Comment: Will this include values for ONLY columns id and name?  What if I need to generalize this to include all columns, without having to explicitly write them in the query?

Answer (score 2):

If it's mysql and the tables are identical, then this should work:

```
REPLACE INTO table1 SELECT * FROM table2;
```

Answer (score 0):

Code also works when a `group by` and `having` clauses are used. Tested SQL 2012 (11.0.5058) Tab1 is source with new records, Tab 2 is the destination to be updated. Tab 2 also has an Identity column. (Yes folks, real world is not as neat and clean as the lab assignments)

```
INSERT INTO Tab2
SELECT  a.T1,a.T2,a.T3,a.T4,a.Val1,a.Val2,a.Val3,a.Val4,-9,-9,-9,-9,MIN(hits) MinHit,MAX(hits) MaxHit,SUM(count) SumCnt, count(distinct(week)) WkCnt
FROM Tab1 a 
LEFT OUTER JOIN Tab2 b ON b.t1 = a.t1 and b.t2 = a.t2 and b.t3 = a.t3 and b.t4 = a.t4 and b.val1 = a.val1 and b.val2 = a.val2  and b.val3 = a.val3  and b.val4 = a.val4 
WHERE b.t1 IS NULL or b.Val1 is NULL
group by a.T1,a.T2,a.T3,a.T4,a.Val1,a.Val2,a.Val3,a.Val4 having MAX(returns)<4 and COUNT(distinct(week))>2 ;
```

Answer (score 0):

This will insert the missing records into Table1

```
INSERT INTO Table2
(Col1, Col2....)
(
SELECT   Col1, Col2,... FROM Table1
EXCEPT
SELECT  Col1, Col2,... FROM Table2
)
```

You can then run an update query to match the records that differ.

```
UPDATE Table2
SET
Col1= T1.Col1,
Col2= T1.Col2,
FROM
Table T1
INNER JOIN
Table2 T2
ON
T1.Col1 = T2.Col1
```