# Write SQL Cursor to populate all the missing rows on the extension table.

Tags: sql, cursor

I am trying to update a table from one column to another column and once I executed the script, discovered that not all the rows updated.  I was told I needed to write a SQL cursor to populate all missing rows on another table.  Issue is, I am not sure how to form a cursor statement.   All the how - tos I am reading are rather vague and don't explain anything.  Would anyone have some basic hints on this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need a cursor? If you want to insert missing tables from one table to another refer to the following post... [Insert missing records from one table to another using mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13053052/insert-missing-records-from-one-table-to-another-using-mysql)